# Are final functors stable under pullback?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, limits-colimits

Recall the notion of a [final functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+functor), which is a sort of colimit-preservation property.
Is such class of functors stable under pullbacks in Cat? Namely, is the pullback of a final functor along any other functor still final? If not, what is a counterexample?

A reference would also be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, final functors are not stable under pullback in general.

Let $I := \{0\to1\}$ be the walking arrow category, then $1:*\to I$ picks out the terminal object and is thus final. The diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\varnothing @>>> *\\
@V{F}VV @VV{1}V\\
* @>>{0}> I
\end{CD}
is a pullback square, but the functor $F:\varnothing\to*$ is not final. Indeed, let $G:*\to\mathbf{Set}$ pick any nonempty set $X$, then $\varinjlim G=X$, but $\varinjlim G\circ F=\varnothing$ since the colimit of the empty diagram is just the initial object in $\mathbf{Set}$. As the unique map $\varnothing\to X$ is not bijective, we can conclude that $F$ is not final despite the finality of $1:*\to I$.

However, final functors form an [orthogonal factorisation system](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/orthogonal+factorization+system) with [discrete fibrations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/discrete+fibration), and so in particular are closed under *pushouts* in $\mathbf{Cat}$ (see e.g., [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weak+factorization+system#ClosureProperties))